# React Native can't add two parameters together in image source

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm parsing items from .json file to my FlatList. But I want to do such a thing but I couldn't do so far...
The problem is the following;

.
.
.

```
 "thumbnail": {
          "path": "http://i.annihil.us/u/prod/marvel/i/mg/b/40/image_not_available",
          "extension": "jpg"
        },
```

And,

```
 const Post = props => {
  const post = props.post;

  return (
 
    <View styles={styles.container}>
      {/*Comics Image*/}
      <View style={styles.imgContainer}>
        <Image style={styles.img}  source={uri: {post.thumbnail.path+post.thumbnail.extension}} /> 
      </View>
```

I did lots of stuff like that none of them worked.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: <Image style={styles.img} source={uri: post.thumbnail.path+post.thumbnail.extension} /> ---for uri http                      
<Image style={styles.img} source={require( post.thumbnail.path+post.thumbnail.extension)} /> ---for link of documents

Comment: @AshleyBrown bcs it didn't showed the thumbnail?

Comment: @ThắngTrươngKhắc  Unexpected token, expected "}" (16:46)  <Image style={styles.img}  source={uri: {post.thumbnail.path+post.thumbnail.extension}} />

Comment: Invalid call at line 16: require(post.thumbnail.path + post.thumbnail.extension) @ThắngTrươngKhắc

Comment: That is the link of the directory path

Comment: <Image style={styles.img} source={uri: post.thumbnail.path+post.thumbnail.extension} /> ---for uri http and no writed wrong redundancy {}

Answer (score 0):

Component Image `source` property take object as it value, for example:

```js
source={{
  uri: 'https://link.to/your/image',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
     Authorization: 'your.token',
  }
}}
```

In your case, the correct `source` should be

```js
source={{uri: post.thumbnail.path+post.thumbnail.extension}}
```

Aware there are 2 `{}` quotes

Comment: thanks for your advice, I fixed the problem with your advice. with the following source={{uri: post.thumbnail.path+'.'+post.thumbnail.extension}}

Comment: Yeah, I missed that dot. haha